# Why BlazorWebApp Interactive model WebAssembly create two projects in it in .NET8?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I was just Exploring the Blazor and its all interactive models as well.
We have Two Templates After .NET 8 "Blazor WebAssembly Standalon" and "Blazor Web App" When you select Blazor Web App and Interactive mode as a Server you get only one project in the Solution Explorer, When you chose Auto you get two projects One is Server and other is WebAssembly that make sense as well, but when you chose Web Assembly as interactive mode in Blazor WebApp You get two projects init. When it is only Web Assembly what is the purpose of other project in it? It do not have any controllers etc for API as well so can't say it BlazorWebAssembly(Hosted) replacment please explain this thing

[image: Image of Blazor Web App Intractive mode WebAssembly Selected].

**What I was expacting**

On Selection of BlazorWebApp -> Interactive Mode -> Web Assembly I was expecting one project in Solution explorer.

Comment: Because how would you serve your WASM to the browser if all the code is WASM? What if you did actually need an API endpoint? Rarely are people making fully front end things.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I can add a WEB Api project in WebAssembly Standalone project as well.
If I dont want to keep my project full front end I would go for Blazor Auto.
why two projects for Web Assembly Render mode.

Comment: It's the Hosted version of WASM - same as ticking the hosted box in the Net7 template.  The Server project provides the web server and pre-rendering.  If you want pure stand alone use the StandAlone template.  It's only a template that builds solutions in different ways.  You can add an empty solution if you like and then add your projects manually.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious difference is you could still use "static server prerender" in BlazorWebApp while cannot in standalone. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes
use `@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(false))` to disable "prerender", then the component will not load until all resources finished download like "standalone".

You could also do more such as add mvc,razorpages,api to Blazor Web app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-8.0#blazor-webassembly.

Anyway, if you just need a pure front-end. Choose standalone is alright.